# Accessing the macos special characters lists programmatically

Tags: macos, automation

I often use special characters (especially mathlike symbols, greek letters, and emoji) when typing. I have an Alfred workflow for emoji which makes it really fast to insert what I want into apps (for those apps which don't allow `:emoji-code:` finding of emoji.

There's nothing for special characters like sigma, alpha, implies, member-of, etc. which I use all the time. The macos character viewer is annoying as opening it is both slow, and it doesn't automatically focus, and keyboard-only friendly.

Therefore I want to access these lists programmatically (to write an Alfred workflow, for example) without having to compile/maintain a list of characters myself, so I can have really rapid, keyboard-only access to these things from anywhere in the OS.

The Alfred workflow uses [emojilib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emojilib), but I can't find an equivalent library for special chars (and the macos character viewer has a huge number of them).

Comment: While not what you probably want, it's worth mentioning that the character viewer has a mode that opens an inline popup instead which has auto-focus on the search field for quickly adding emojis & symbols. The mode can be activated by the top-right icon (the one that is like a window with a ⌘) and pops up via the same keyboard shortcut (control + command + space) by default.

Comment: That does work, but I'd still be curious to know if there's a good way of accessing the character list programmatically.

Comment: I guess you would have to go through the [unicode list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) but if we are talking about a small set of special characters that you often use, why don't you just define a few text replacements in `Preferences > Keyboard > Text`? It would be fast, system-wide and synced across devices...